# Function $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ neither injective nor surjective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Question: **"Give an example of a function $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ that is neither injective nor surjective."**

I wanted to check whether this is a valid answer.

$$g(n)=\vert\lfloor{\sqrt{n+1}}\rfloor\vert$$
It is not injective because e.g., $g(0)=g(1)=g(2)=1$ and $0\neq1\neq2.$

It is not surjective because $g(n)\neq0$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Why not $g(n)=1$?

Comment: This looks ok, but it's usually easier to use piecewise functions instead of the standard functions.

Comment: Correct, but much more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overly complicated, but indeed correct.